How do I fix: Connection Failed. Activation of network connection failed

I purchased a (No Name) USB bluetooth 5.0 device.
When I inserted the device the OS immediately picked it up.
Before I connected any devices, mobile phone or earphones, I got the following message after a few minutes:
“Connection Failed.
Activation of network connection failed.”
When I switched on my bluetooth earphones, Jabra, after the usual pairing they connected and I could listen to music using VLC, however, I got a crackling noise every now and then which sometimes coincided with a display of “Connection Failed.
Activation of network connection failed.”
The sound quality was also not consistent, so, I returned the USB device assuming that it was faulty.
I subsequently purchased a WINX 5.1 USB Bluetooth device.
When I insert the device the OS immediately picks it up.
Before I connect any devices, mobile phone or earphones, I get the following message after a few minutes:
“Connection Failed.
Activation of network connection failed.”
When I switch on my bluetooth earphones , Jabra, after the usual pairing they connect and I can listen to music using VLC or Youtube using firefox. Every now and then there is a crackling sound which sometimes coincides with a display of “Connection Failed.
Activation of network connection failed.”
The music quality sound is good and is only affected by the crackling sound.
When I connect my mobile phone to the PC using bluetooth I can listen to music after the pairing has been done.  The message   “Connection Failed.
Activation of network connection failed.” keeps coming up every now and then. The quality of the music sound is good and no crackling is heard but I suspect that it has to do with the fact that the music data is being streamed to the mobile phone and then played whereas the mode of operation to the earphones is different.
PLEASE HELP !
WHAT IS THE CAUSE OF THE MESSAGE AND HOW CAN I FIX IT ?

Hardware Model:     Gigabyte Technology Co.,Ltd
Memory:             16.0 GiB
Processor:          Intel Core i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz x 8
Graphics:           AMD Cedar
Disk Capacity:      1.8TB
OS:                 Ubuntu 22.04.4  LTS
OS Type:            64-bit
GNOME Version:      42.9
Windowing System:   X11
NO WIFI.
I use an ethernet connection on my PC. My PC has no wifi capabilities.

Are you using wifi at the same time?  If so edit the question to inlcude results from terminal for lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb
